# How to add a '-' apex in Python

Tags: python, unicode, character

I have a problem: i can't find the '-' apex character...
i'm writing code on math function: and i want to insert representation like 
², ³.
i found that 
print '\xb2, \xb3' work good.
now, i have to insert negative numbers at the apex, like :¯².
so, i need the ¯ charachter. 
How can i find that?

Comment: ok, on IDLE it seems like here, that is to say a big '-' on the top...
i want something like http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potenza_(matematica)
plesa, help

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> print('\xaf')       # or '\u00af'
¯                       # macron
>>> print('\u2212')
−                       # minus
>>> print('\u207b')
⁻                       # superscript minus
```

You'll need `u''` notation in python-2.x

Comment: you are a very kind person!!
thaks very very very much!!

Comment: @ant yes, as we say on SO: thanks are nice but acceptance matters -- just click on the checkmark-shaped icon under the big digit on SilentGhost's answer upper left!

Comment: sorry, but i'm not registered... the next time i will :)